# For Taylor expansion of Hyperbolic Secant, how to find radius of convergence?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Say, expand $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ at $x=0$. Wikipedia gives $\pi/2$ but there's no further details. I wonder how to find that?

Comment: Do you know the zeros of $\cosh $ in the complex plane? (They are related to the zeros of $\cos $ on the real line)

Comment: See [OEIS A$046976$](https://oeis.org/A046976) and [OEIS A$046977$](https://oeis.org/A046977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathrm{sech}(ix)=\sec(x)$. Which singularity of $\sec(x)$ is closest to $0$?

The radius of convergence of $f(z)$ about $z=a$ is the distance from $a$ to the closest singularity of $f$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis).